# Windows Service Config not updating

Tags: c#, service, config

I've got a windows service coded in c#, with a config file:

```
ProcessingService.exe
ProcessingService.exe.config
```

Its got a webservice endpoint address in it. This initially went in with the wrong address, so I stopped the service, changed the config file and restarted, but the service is still hitting the original URL.

I then restarted the entire server and still the wrong URL is being accessed.

We have a load of corporate rules about new install versions meaning my turnaround time for compiling a new service and getting it installed will be measured in weeks, leaving the URL broken for that entire time. Is there a way to force the config to update?

(Yes, I've triple checked that the config file is now correct!)

In response to the request for the service setup code, I simply do (class names changed):

```
WebserviceNamespace.ServiceClass client = new WebserviceNamespace.ServiceClass();
```

The service config shows the original URL, and I'm using a transformed app.config process to overwrite the new URL in the new config file (again, I've triple checked this). I am generating the service classes as internal though, could this be something to do with it?

OK, so I've now tried installing the service on another computer, stopping it, changing the URL in the config to "nevergonnahappen" and restarted. Requests to that now fail on an invalid url. So it must be something to do with our live server specifically...

Comment: You need to uninstall and install again your service.

Comment: @User.Anonymous no, you don't. Creating a service merely maps an executable to a service name, it doesn't magically cache its .NET configuration. - Chris, show the code where you instantiate the service client.

Comment: Are you sure? All the other articles I've looked at say a restart is enough, thus my confusion. What is the difference here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039365/windows-services-is-it-advisable-to-update-its-config-file-while-running

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster, comments amended above

Comment: I'm using many windows service on my application and I'm agree that in theorical matter a restart is enough (on my dev computer, that working fine). But I have seen too many time the config not updated when I'm working on another environnement, that I use now a .bat with installutil /u and installutil to be sure to have the last version. And in most case, we don't have time to investigate more why it don't work when a new install remove the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure that your services is pulling the url from config file.
2. make sure the services is not cached the url somewhere else after getting it(maybe in memory or file or database).
3. make sure you pointed to correct folder for the config file, perhaps do a wild search with agent ransack, any other place that is still writing broken url and your services in fact is pointing into it.

Comment: Debugging tips can be posted as comments, not answers.

Comment: All of these have been checked yes, see the edits above

Comment: but only user with reputation 50 can reply on other's comment,a bit more for me to go.

@ChrisSurfleet, another hits that I think of, perhaps you can remove the config content, see if your service still able to start or throw error.

Comment: Yeah I gave that a go - I removed the entry entirely and no change. Its bizarre how this sticks around even after a full server restart, yet on all other servers a restart of the service is enough. The servers are supposedly clones as well!

Comment: it happened to me once few years back, but that time is I trying to modify the app.config instead of myservice.exe.config, look like it's not same with your case. 

Since you still got the installer as you tried on other server and it work, why don't you just try the last step, uninstall and reinstall back, before you start the service, update the config file 1st.

while you doing this, please raise the change request to recompile the build in case above step fail so it won't drag your timeline.